# Query for retrieving columns with null value

Tags: sql, postgresql

Considering the following table

```
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|Col01|Col02|Col03|Col04|Col05|Col06|   <===header
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|data1|data2|NULL |hi   |Hello|Folks|   <===a row
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now I would like to have a query which returns the name of column ( in this case `COL03`) or the column number as result which has a null value.

How can I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Do you want this for one specific row or multiple of them?

Comment: Call your column SELECT NULLIF(col03, 3) as col03

Comment: @PatrickHofman yes buddy, within a single row.

Comment: Do you also need col1, col2, etc. or just col3?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I need any index/name of columns(probably it will be only 1) which has got null value dear :D

Comment: which version of PostgreSQL do you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this do?

```
select case
       when col01 is null
       then 'col1'
       when col02 is null
       then 'col2'
       when col03 is null
       then 'col3'
       when col04 is null
       then 'col4'
       when col05 is null
       then 'col5'
       else null
       end
       which_col
from   tableX
```

If you want to construct this dynamically, I think you have to go procedural. You can get the name of the columns by querying information_schema.columns. Then create a query like this using that information.

Comment: Hmm, perfect dear, perfect, so one more thing, what if the columns are dynamically changing? I mean in future I may have less or more columns, is there anything in order to make this query dynamic as column numbers.

Comment: I think you have to go procedural then. You can get the name of the columns by querying `information_schema.columns`. Then create a query like this using that information.

Comment: Not for now dear, come back if I have one.

Answer (score 1):

This will return row for each column in your table that has null value.

```
SELECT 'Col1' FROM MyTable WHERE col1 IS NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Col2' FROM MyTable WHERE col2 IS NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT 'Col3' FROM MyTable WHERE col3 IS NULL
```

Comment: I think the OP wants the column name or index as in the question, not the value of `col3`. Which is always `null` in your query by the way...

Comment: He is asking for `Null` value. Which is exactly what I give him.

Comment: Question states 'which returns the COL03 or the column index as result', not the value.

Comment: @VladimirOselsky Buddy, Patrick is right, I don't know which column has got the null value, I need the column index or name itself. this is possible that col4 or 1 goes null too.

Comment: So you want to get column name back that has null value?

Comment: @VladimirOselsky yes dear, either name or index number B-)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select 'col1' from Table1 where col1 is null
union all
select 'col2' from Table1 where col2 is null
....
union all
select 'colN' from Table1 where colN is null
```